# Symfony2 Login with security provider and sha1/sha512 with more than one iteration

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

I want to create a login in symfony2 that uses a user database table. The login runs with the encoders "plaintext", "sha1" (1 iteration, encode_as_base64: false), "sha512" (1 iteration, encode_as_base64: false).

Astonishingly it is not running with more than one iterations.

I have a "chain_providers" statement in my "security.yml" with two providers "in_memory" and "user_db" (=login with a user database). The first has no problems.

Let's use two iterations for example:

"security.yml":

```
security:
    encoders:
        Customer\MyBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 2
            encode_as_base64: false
...
    user_db:
        entity:
            class: Customer\MyBundle\Entity\User
            property: login
```

Now I calculate a new password hash:

```
php -r '$pw = "new2"; $iter = 2; for ($i = 1; $i<= $iter; $i++) $pw = hash("sha512", $pw); print "pw ($iter): $pw\n";'
```

And I write this into the "password" column of my users entity (MySQL table):

```
update User set password = "239055fb839647cfd3d58d542db192aae36f108ebbe1a16e71d25178bc455b6a94e81e34fd96f8953663d9a3206ad23512d4b79ea78cc1f0bdbcc08275c732b6" where login="test";
```

I should be able to login now but all I get is "Bad credentials".

My user Entity implements interface "UserInterface". my getSalt() method returns an empty string or null (both tested). There's nothing special with getUsername() or getRoles().

What can be the problem with the iterations?
Why is it running only for "iterations: 1" / "$iter = 1"?

Answer (score 1):

The multiple-hashed password is created in another way than expected.

The code in MessageDigestPasswordEncoder::encodePassword($raw, $salt) is:

```
    ...
    $salted = $this->mergePasswordAndSalt($raw, $salt);
    $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $salted, true);

    // "stretch" hash
    for ($i = 1; $i < $this->iterations; $i++) {
        $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $digest.$salted, true);
    }

    return $this->encodeHashAsBase64 ? base64_encode($digest) : bin2hex($digest);
```

..with "mergePasswordAndSalt()" returning the $raw password for an empty $salt.

In other words: for an empty $salt it appends the original password to the hashed password in each iteration.

To offline generate a new password we need this changed code:

```
$pw = "neu";
$digest = "";
$salted = $pw; // for emtpy salt
for ($i = 1; $i<= 4398; $i++)
{
    $digest = hash("sha512", $digest . $salted, true);
}
print base64_encode($digest) . "\n";
// now write the generated code into the password in the database table
```

And setup this in the security.yml:

```
security:
  encoders:
    Customer\MyBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: sha512
        iterations: 4398
        encode_as_base64: true
```